# JavaScript array and object addition

Tags: javascript

I'm testin some JavaScript concepts and I'm trying to understand why:

```
typeof({} + {})
typeof([] + [])
```

return a 'string' yet:

```
typeof {}
typeof []
```

return an 'object'

I've tried this in NodeJS, FireFox, Chrome and IE9 all with the same results.

Comment: Your observations all have to do with the semantics of the `+` operator, as is easily confirmed by [reading the language spec.](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.6.1)

Comment: I'm guessing that because the addition of objects and arrays make no sense to the compiler/interpreter that it's doing a toString() on these objects before concatenating them. Is this right?

Comment: Yes - check out the link I just edited into my comment.

Comment: Interestingly, on the Chrome console, `{} + {}` gives `NaN` and `typeof(NaN)` give `"number"`

Comment: @Dancrumb the constant `NaN` is a primitive number instance, though that seems weird.

Comment: @Dancrumb `{} + {}` is not the same as `({} + {})`. The first `{}` is treated as an empty block, so it is equivalent to `+{}`. With unary `+`, the operand is always converted to a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator is defined to either concatenate strings or add numbers. If you try something else, the operands have to be converted to strings or numbers first. It looks like string is preferred here.

You can control what `string` or `number` is returned by defining functions `.toString` and `.valueOf` on the objects respectively

Answer (score 1):

You can't concatenate or "add" arrays or objects using the + operator.

If you add two objects their string-representations are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator attempts to coerce the operands to a common type. In this case, the type is string, since adding objects or arrays does not make any sense.

From the `+` operator documentation:

> If Type(lprim) is String or Type(rprim) is String, then
>   Return the String that is the result of concatenating ToString(lprim) followed by ToString(rprim)

Since the default value of an object is a string (an empty string, in the case of an empty object), the return value of the operation is `'' + '' => ''`.

See the ECMAScript documentation for the [`+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1), [`ToPrimitive`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1), and an object's [`DefaultValue`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8) if you care about the internals.